# Magento 2.2 - How to redirect url with store code to url without store code?

Tags: magento2, redirect, store-code

The site is been indexed on Google with Store Code for each store view (it/en/gb/au) now the store codes are been removed from url, so all the links end up in a 404 error.
How can I set an automatic redirect to the new links without store code for all the catalog? It may be possible with the .htaccess file?

From
https://example.com/en/{something}.html
to
https://example.com/{something}.html

Comment: are you tried re compiling and reindexing already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution doing this simple Observer, I share the code, maybe it could be useful for someone else.

```
    <?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ForceRedirectObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $urlParts = [];
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
       $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $this->urlParts = parse_url($this->url->getCurrentUrl());
        $pathChecker = $this->urlParts['path'];

        if(strpos($pathChecker, 'it') == 1){
            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: " . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . substr($pathChecker, 4));
            exit();
        }
        if(strpos($pathChecker, 'en') == 1){
            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: " . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . substr($pathChecker, 4));
            exit();
        }
        if(strpos($pathChecker, 'gb') == 1){
            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: " . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . substr($pathChecker, 4));
            exit();
        }
        if(strpos($pathChecker, 'au') == 1){
            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: " . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . substr($pathChecker, 4));
            exit();
        }


    }
}
```